# linear independence, vectorspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

is my proof for the following task correct?

> Let $f:V\to W$ be a linear function and $\{v_1,v_2,\dotso, v_n\}$ a base of $V$ >and $w_i\in W$ with $f(v_i)=w_i$.
>
> Let $f$ be injective. Show, that the vectors $w_1, w_2,\dotso w_n$ are linear >independent.

Proof:

The vectors $w_1,\dotso, w_n$ are linear independent, if

$k_1w_1+\dotso +k_nw_n=0\Rightarrow k_1=0, \dotso, k_n=0$ for $k_i\in K$

It is:

$k_1w_1+\dotso+k_nw_n=k_1f(v_1)+\dotso+ k_nf(v_n)=f(k_1v_1)+\dotso+f(k_nv_n)$
$=f(k_1v_1+\dotso k_nv_n)=0_W$

Since $f$ injective it is

$k_1v_1+\dotso k_nv_n=0_V$ and as $\{v_1,\dotso, v_n\}$ is a base of $V$, $v_1,\dotso, v_n$ are linear independent.

Hence $k_1=0,\dotso, k_n=0$

$\square$

Thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: I would change "It is ..." to "Suppose $0_W=k_1w_1 + \ldots$" just so it is clear that you start with the assumption that the linear combination equals 0 and then your conclusion is that the coefficients must be 0. Looks good though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof looks good to me. Another way to show this is that $f$ is injective if and only if $\ker f=0$.

Suppose that 
$$a_1f(v_1)+\dots+a_n f(v_n)=0$$

where $a_i, \dots,a_j \neq 0$ for some collection of coefficients above. Then $f(a_i v_i+\dots a_jv_j)=0$, implying that $f$ has nontrivial kernel.

Comment: There's no need to invoke contradiction.

Comment: True. ${}{}{}{}$